# Ionic ios capacitor splash screen working, but unable to add images

Tags: ios, angular, splash-screen, capacitor

I am trying to display a custom splash screen using ionic capacitor. I followed the splash screen documentation and got it working for general color backgrounds. But when I attempt to add images, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

capacitor.config.json:

```
"SplashScreen": {
   "launchShowDuration": 2000,
  "launchAutoHide": false,
  "backgroundColor": "#00FF00",
  "androidSplashResourceName": "splash",
  "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP",
  "showSpinner": false,
  "androidSpinnerStyle": "large",
  "iosSpinnerStyle": "small",

  "spinnerColor": "#999999",
  "splashFullScreen": true,
  "splashImmersive": true,
  "layoutName": "launch_screen",
  "useDialog": true
 },
```

app.component.ts:

```
console.log('waiting starts!')
SplashScreen.show({
  showDuration: 2000,
  autoHide: true
});


this.platform.ready().then(async() => 
{
  console.log('waiting ends')
  SplashScreen.hide()

  StatusBar.setStyle({style:Style.Default});
  ...
```

source: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen

In my json file I had the screen set to green (with the `backgroundColor` parameter), which works:

[image: Green Screen]

But I am unable to get the splash image to work using this documentation: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons. This is my current setup:

[image]

[image]

And after following this tutorial (https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-icons-splash-screens-launch-images-to-capacitor-projects/) and running `cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy` it doesn't work. Does anyone know what is going wrong? I think it may have something to do with my launchscreen storyboard. Earlier in the project, someone else messed around with it so now it looks like this:

[image]

Note: the test image I was using for the splash screen is just a blue canvas, so that's what is on the splash asset if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS the Splash plugin uses the configured Launch Storyboard (`LaunchScreen.storyboard` by default), so if you messed with it that can be the reason why it no longer works.
It should contain a ImageView that loads the Splash.png image.
Well, you don't really need to show the image, whatever you add to it will be shown, images, texts.

On Android, as you configured the `layoutName`, it will use whatever you have in the layout called `launch_screen.xml` and not the image.

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem. The image wasn't set up at all so I added the splash.png asset and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, install cordova-res:

> npm install -g cordova-res

cordova-res expects a Cordova-like structure: place one icon and one splash screen file in a top-level **resources** folder within your project, like so:

resources/

├── icon.png

└── splash.png

Next, run the following to generate all images then copy them into the native projects:

```
cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy
cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
```

resources/icon.(png|jpg) must be at least 1024×1024px

resources/splash.(png|jpg) must be at least 2732×2732px

Comment: If you look at what I put in my original post, that's what I did.

Comment: @DarrowHartman Yes i checked for custom splash screen as image. You can follow this.